# Center Navigation

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I've tried everything I can find and I'm sure it's a simple fix but I cannot get this navigation centered. Working on customizing this theme: (demo) http://femininethemesdemo.com/themes/quinn/ for a client. The original theme has social icons to the right and am curious if that is getting in the way (client doesn't want them for her site.) Either way, any help is appreciated!

CSS

/* .nav */

```
  .tinynav {display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}
  .nav-section {background: #fff3ee; width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8; position: fixed; z-index: 9999;}
  .nav-section hr {height: 3px; background: #fff; margin: 0; border: none;}
  .nav {position: relative; width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 15px 0; clear: both; font-size: .80em; line-height: 1em; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: .2em;}
  .nav ul {list-style: none; display: none;}
  .nav a {display: block; padding: 20px 12px; color: #000;}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the best way to go about this, is to make the social icons NOT be a part of the navigation. Then you could make the nav width 100% and center it. Then put the icons on top of the nav (open space) on the right or current location. If you create a fiddle, I could piece something together for you :)

Comment: The navigation is centered in my browser (chrome). I don't see the problem.